# Как менять параметр функции внутри другой функции?

Tags: python

Высчитываю двойной интеграл степенной функции

```
def dbl_integral(f, a1, b1, a2, b2, n1, n2):
    j = 0
    N = b1 - a1
    h = (n2-n1)/N
    n = n1
    I = []

    while j != N:
        f = lambda x, y: x**n # здесь надо менять не всю функцию напрямую а лишь изменять параметр n
        i = scipy.integrate.dblquad(f, a1, b1, a2, b2)[0]
        I.append(i)
        n += h
        j += 1
    return I
```

Я хочу потом этот метод использовать и под другие похожие функции, все что мне надо делать это менять параметр n внутри функции, а сейчас получается так что я переписываю полностью всю функцию(хардкод кароче). Как можно это решить?

Comment: а почему переписываете, это же аргумент функции? n = n1 к тому же он меняется на каждом шаге цикла n += h

Comment: @splash58 иначе функция будет высчитывать n только по начальному заданному ей значению, а так я каждый раз обновляю это n

Comment: Чем плохо текущее решение? `n` меняется, всё считается. Что не так?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Так то оно так, да, но если я захочу поменять функцию, то мне придеться менять ее и внутри самой функции dbl_integral, а хотелось бы сделать так что я создал определенную функцию, передал ее в dbl_integral и она все решила без прямых изменений этой функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите `fn` как функцию трёх аргументов (`fn = lambda n, x, y: x ** n`). Внутри `dbl_integral` определите функцию двух аргументов, в ней `n` фиксировано (`f = lambda x, y: fn(n, x, y)`):

```
def dbl_integral(fn, a1, b1, a2, b2, n1, n2):
    j = 0
    N = b1 - a1
    h = (n2-n1)/N
    n = n1
    I = []

    while j != N:
        f = lambda x, y: fn(n, x, y) # здесь надо менять не всю функцию напрямую а лишь изменять параметр n
        i = scipy.integrate.dblquad(f, a1, b1, a2, b2)[0]
        I.append(i)
        n += h
        j += 1
    return I

...
print(dbl_integral(lambda n, x, y: x ** n, a1, b1, a2, b2, n1, n2)
```